# How to delete () in by sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

For example

I'd like trans:

```
M:HelloWorld:main(java.lang.String[]) (S)HelloWorld:foo()
```

To:

```
HelloWorld:main  HelloWorld:foo
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is always recommended to post your efforts which you have put to solve this problem as we all are here to learn.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

Try with regex to pull the desired result

```
(?:(HelloWorld:\w*)\(.*?\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MopKnb/1)